# In Xcode ( Interface Builder) why UI Elements like UIView, UILabel, UITextField ... not responding to AutoLayout properties while try to modify?

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout

When UI Elements like UILabel or UIView placed into Storyboard or nib, It some times happened that, UI Elements not responding to AutoLayout Property changing.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

In this case just go to "Size Inspector" Tab of Interface Builder of XCode and you have to just change the value of property name "**Layout**".
just change value from "**Autoresizing Mask**" to "**Inherited (Autoresizing Mask)**"
[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ2CD.png)